# what is wrong with this query using str_to-date function?

Tags: mysql, sql, str-to-date

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`REPORTDATETIME`,' ',1),'%m/%d/%y') 
FROM crimes 
where REPORTDATETIME like '%1/12/2001%'
```

it is the query which iam using 
reportdatetime(varchar) is the column name of table

```
reportdatetime
1/12/2001 1:30
12/23/2003 1:09
11/12/2001 1:30
5/23/2003 1:09
```

the result which query gives

```
2020-1-12
```

but the result iam expecting is 2001-1-12

Comment: You main problem is that your STR_TO_DATE format should be '%m/%d/%Y' for a four-digit year.

Answer (score 1):

Your `STR_TO_DATE` format should be `'%m/%d/%Y'` for a four-digit year.

Other peripheral issues to note... I would expect your WHERE clause to catch two different rows (always best to avoid using a leading '%' in LIKE whenever you can).  Also, a time of `1:90` looks very strange.

Comment: opps do not worry about time it is dumy.i am skipping  time and only getting date